# Chrome OS on a VM?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, remote-access, remote, google-chrome-os

This may be a moot point, but can I run ChromeOS on a VM? [CloudReady Home Edition](https://www.neverware.com/freedownload) looks good, but is that it? Is [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/) a viable option?

Purpose - Here's the requirement: I want to run a legacy G-Suite account on an OS. Here's my biggest issue: I also want to access it remotely, which is why I was thinking about using a VM on a server.

Alternatives and suggestions - Are there better ways of doing this? Or maybe ditching a ChromeOS or any other Instant OS ( like the now defunct [Splashtop OS](http://web.archive.org/web/20120622225343/http://www.splashtop.com:80/os) ) options for [Deepin](https://www.deepin.org/en/), [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io/) or something simpler like [Q4OS](http://www.q4os.org/), [Endless OS](https://endlessos.com/) or even [ReactOS](https://reactos.org/)?

Free options are best, but I'd consider inexpensive one-off costs as well. As far as the hardware, I could even use a Raspberry pi for this, but I think a PC or Mac server's more realistic.

I prefer easy-to-install, easy-to-use ( like ChromeOS ) as well as easy-on-the-eyes, and/or theme-able OSes, but it should be able to run (a) Google Apps-compatible browser(s). Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Alternatives and suggestions are best addressed in a separate question. We try to stick to one question per question here.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I only added that additional portion because some answers may include these, since others may be trying to do the same thing. I figured I may be trying to reinvent the wheel with ChromeOS because I also want to remote into the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...can I run ChromeOS on a VM?

Yes, you can! Instructions exist to put ChromeOS in VMware Professional (and VMware Workstation before version 15), to wit:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/installation_at_vmware.md

Comment: The NeverWare site now (October 2019) states that the CloudReady image no longer works with VirtualBox aand does not work with V15 of VMWare player due to graphics issues. https://cloudreadykb.neverware.com/s/article/Download-CloudReady-Image-For-VMware

Answer (score 1):

The [overlay-variant-amd64-generic-vmware](https://github.com/FydeOS/overlay-variant-amd64-generic-vmware) project is the closest you can get. Downloadable pre-built images are provided with this project under the "[release](https://github.com/FydeOS/overlay-variant-amd64-generic-vmware/releases)" tab.